# How to reach page of Facebook public event I accidentally declined?

Tags: facebook-events, invitation

A friend invited me to a public event.

I accidentally touched "Can't go", and now the event does not appear anywhere.

- In the "Tab" event of the "Events" page, there is no "Show declined events" link, even in desktop mode.
- I know my friend is marked as going, but no information about the event appears on his profile page.
- I don't remember what the event was called, and searches do not lead to it.
- It is not listed in the "events near you", or other suggested events.

How to find back that event page?

Is begging my friend the only solution?